# What is intrinsic parity? Why is negative intrinsic parity possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, definition, parity

What is intrinsic [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics))? It seems that it is a concept only for relativistic quantum physics. Why is it not relevant for non-relativistic quantum mechanics?

Comment: It's a property of quantum fields, which do not normally feature in NRQM.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_parity

Comment: You *do* understand that fermion fields have an intrinsic parity opposite to that of anti fermion ones, by dint of the Dirac equation, right? In that sense, the parity of composite fields like those of mesons isn't really intrinsic. Is this your question?